# EDIFACT to DB Objects or DB

Tags: c#, translation, edi, altova, edifact

I'm looking for a tool that provides both C# API that we can use in code and a  Script to transform an EDIFACT File (ISO 9735) to XML or other formats such as CSV. We are building a system that will help us to translate EDIFACT data that we get from Client and save in DB or DB objects.

Question: 
1. Can you please recommend any cost effective Tool we can use that will help us to translate EDIFACT (ISO 9735) Data to Other formats such as XML or CSV or DB objects etc. I need both C# API and SCRIPT.

2. Is there any open source API available to do this Job ? A sample EDIFACT file Data is provided below.

Thanks, 
Partha

`FAD+114:526411642:4::TKFAD:1:1+20141220:070825037+1+20141220:070825037'VAI+S:KK+CH:75799099'MGA+S:SSSS+1+1+20141220'OFI+S:SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS+CH:804522+C+175+20150821++3044848+211444238+1+1+100+100+2+CH:804522+++2015:08:21+T1:333'FMB+S:SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS+8++4+1++3+20141220+++TKN:4+++2+501'FMU+S:K+1'VAK+S:KKSSSS+TKN:4+PANERA C 175 AUG15+Option on equity+Call August 175'VAL+S:KKSS+TKN:1+OCC/O PANERA 08 2015 C 175+OCC/O PANERA 08 2015 C 175'VAL+S:KKSS+TKN:2+OCC/O PANERA 08 2015 C 175+OCC/O PANERA 08 2015 C 175'VAL+S:KKSS+TKN:3+OCC/O PANERA 08 2015 C 175+OCC/O PANERA 08 2015 C 175'VAL+S:KKSS+TKN:4+OCC/O PANERA 08 2015 C 175+OCC/O PANERA 08 2015 C 175'GEI+S:KK+GK:709030'GEK+I:KKI+TKN:4+OCC'NKN+S:KSSSS+CH:75799099+20141220++2'FMG+S:KSS+TKT+Z'FMG+S:KSS+TKPRK+1'FMG+S:KSS+CFI+OCASPS+3`

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: You are going to get automatically banned if you ask any more questions like this.

Comment: Why ? I'm asking for recommendations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various `C#/Java` parsers on the internet to map `EDIFACT` to `XML` or vice versa. One example is https://github.com/DonZoeggerle/ediFabric. Look [here](http://x12parser.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparing%20Open%20Source%20EDI%20Software) for a comparison of several packages.

Example DTM segment from an MSCONS message:

```
DTM+137:200603241322:203'
```

Corresponding `XML` snippet:

```
<DTM_Date_Time_Period_0030>
  <Date_Time_Period>
    <Date_Time_Period_010>
      <C507_Date_Time_Period>
        <Date_Or_Time_Or_Period_Function_Code_Qualifier_010>137
        </Date_Or_Time_Or_Period_Function_Code_Qualifier_010>
        <Date_Or_Time_Or_Period_Text_020>200603241322
        </Date_Or_Time_Or_Period_Text_020>
        <Date_Or_Time_Or_Period_Format_Code_030>203
        </Date_Or_Time_Or_Period_Format_Code_030>
      </C507_Date_Time_Period>
    </Date_Time_Period_010>
  </Date_Time_Period>
</DTM_Date_Time_Period_0030>
```

It becomes apparent that `XML` might take much more space than `EDIFACT`.

There seems to be no commonly accepted standard how to represent `EDIFACT` in `XML`. It is possible to map every `EDIFACT` segment into an `XML` construct. This requires to split the `EDIFACT` segment into data elements and data fields and translate them to `XML` tags and/or attributes. But this "flat" representation does not reflect the nested structure of most `EDIFACT` messages. Without knowing the underlying message structure, a parser cannot translate into a meaningful `XML`.

The pure mapping of `EDIFACT` to `XML` is only a small fraction of the bill. Other required steps include:

- communication between the business partners (mail, `AS2`, managed file transfer)
- acknowledgements (sending/receiving `EDIFACT` `CONTRL`/`APERAK` messages)
- encryption/decryption
- signature/validation
- administration of *B2B* partner data (addresses, message types, contacts, ...)
- error handling
- performance management
- splitting and joining messages
- message routing
- spam protection
- logging/monitoring

This long list gives good reasons to look at commercial **B2B** platforms if you have more than a handful of **B2B** connections to be taken care of.

Comment: Thanks Axel. Did you use Edifebric to convert EDIFACT data to XML ? Also it would be great if you please recommend few commercial tools (not open source) that are stable and widely used in Industry. Thanks.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here. But personally, I am a satisfied customer of Seeburger http://www.seeburger.com/